# image colors in pdf files in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image, pdf

I'm creating a program to generate PDF files in VB.Net.

Everything is working fine except that the image is being displayed with a blue background while the image provided doesn't have any.

Following are the lines of code being used:

```
sColor = IIf(mvarEncodeASCII85, ToASCII85(ImgColor),
    (System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(ImgColor)))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is not alot of details, but my first thougt is that it is .png-files or .gif-files.
Am I correct? In that case it may be an issue with adobe acrobat handling the transparent backgrounds.

As I said it's hard to say exactly without any further details.